# Word 2010: How to Edit/View existing Add-ins Menu Commands and Custom Toolbar Items

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am the developer of a Word 2010 wizard file (actually created with an earlier version of Word) that has a Menu Command and a number of Custom Toolbars items on the Add-ins tab.

I have found information on how to add new tabs and how to modify the ribbon, but I can't find a way to edit/view existing Menu Commands and Custom Toolbar items in the Add-ins menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the Add-ins ribbon tab is created automatically to show the commandbar items of add-ins from former versions of Word, e.g. Word 2003. Goal was to allow users to use these add-ins without the need of an explicit user interface conversion.

It is not clear from your question if you are the user or the developer of the add-in. If you are the developer, you can convert your add-in to the dotm file format and just add the ribbon user interface to it. A good resource for a start you may find on the [MVPS Word homepage here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/Customising%20the%20Ribbon%20-%20Advanced.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am the developer (well... I am now) of the add-in.  Let me check out the link you provided and will report back.

Comment: I never was able to edit/view the legacy add-in toolbar items, so I had to recreate all the items from scratch.  I referenced your link her and especially this link - http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Customize_Ribbon.htm  Lots of great info on the greg maxey site.

Comment: Yes, Greg is also a well-know contributor.